# Is there an infinite set $X$ such that for every isotone $f\colon[X]^\omega\to[X]^\omega$ there is a free decreasing sequence?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, infinite-combinatorics

(Pierre Gillibert asked me this question and I post it with his permission.)

Let $X$ be an infinite set, and $f\colon[X]^\omega\to[X]^\omega$. We say that $\{x_n\mid n<\omega\}\subseteq X$ is a *free decreasing sequence* (for $f$) if for all $n$, $x_n\notin f(\{x_k\mid k>n\})$.

> Is there an infinite set $X$ such that for every isotone $f\colon[X]^\omega\to[X]^\omega$ there exists a free decreasing sequence? Is it at least consistent from assumptions such as $V=L$, large cardinals or strong forcing axioms?

Some observations:

1. It is clear that $X$ is uncountable, because otherwise $f(A)=X$ for all $A\in[X]^\omega$ would pose a counterexample.
2. If there is no such set of size $\kappa$, then there is no such example of size $\kappa^+$.
3. If $\kappa$ has uncountable cofinality, and there is no such set of size $<\kappa$, then there is no example of size $\kappa$, since we can "glue" counterexamples and use the fact that every countable set is bounded (this is in effect the same proof for the previous observation).

Comment: You mention "isotone" functions, but what is the order here?

Comment: Inclusion, of course.

Comment: Do you mean that $f(x) \subseteq x$ or $x \subseteq f(x)$ (or something else)?

Comment: @Yair: You can always assume that $x\subseteq f(x)$, by replacing $f$ with $f(x)\cup x$. When I say $f$ is isotone, I just mean that $x\subseteq y$ implies $f(x)\subseteq f(y)$.

Comment: In the definition you write $[X]^\omega$, do you mean $\omega$-sequence of ordinals, or set of ordinals with order type $\omega$ (in the usual order of the ordinals)?

Comment: @Yair: Just the usual definition of $[X]^\omega$. All the countably infinite subsets of $X$.

Comment: What is $f(\{x_k:k>n\})$? $x_k$ are already subsets of $X$, so the set used in the argument of $f$ is an element of $[[X]^\omega]^\omega$ in your notation and we get an argument type mismatch....

Comment: @fedja: I don't see where it was implied that $x_k$ is a subset of $X$ and not an element of $X$. If you point me to that location, I will clarify there.

Comment: Indeed. But it wasn't spelled out that it is an element of $X$ either and with all fancy notation I got totally confused. You are right: there is a unique reading that makes everything fit together, but it is not very easy to discern :-)

Comment: @fedja: Okay, I clarified that.

Comment: I have the feeling that www-cs.stanford.edu/~jbaek/infinite-ramsey.pdf (especially the very end) may be very relevant here, but have no time to follow this avenue myself now, so I'm just attracting your attention to it :-)

Comment: @fedja: Just a general remark, if you put https or http it will be an actual link, not just a bunch of text.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just being stupid, but I don't see how to "glue" counterexamples together. For $\kappa = \omega_1$, I can see that the function $A \mapsto \sup A$ is a counterexample. How do I use this function to build a counterexample for $\omega_2$?

Comment: @Will: Suppose that $\kappa$ has uncountable cofinality, and for every $\alpha<\kappa$, we have $f_\alpha$ is a counterexample. Then for a countable set $A\in[\kappa]^\omega$, define $$f(A)=\bigcup\{f_\alpha(A\cap\alpha)\mid\alpha\in A\cup\{\sup A\}, A\cap\alpha\text{ infinite}\}.$$ Then $f$ is indeed isotone; and if $x_n$ is a free dec. seq., by induction we can refine to assume that $x_n$ is a strictly increase set of type $\omega$. But then $f$ applied to the sequence is just $f_\alpha$ applied to it, and $f_\alpha$ had no free dec. seq.

Comment: @Will: The refinement goes like this, pick the least element that has infinitely many points from the sequence above it, and now start forming a strictly increasing sequence. By isotony, at each point your sequence will be a subsequence of the original sequence, and thus retain the free-ness property. (And for what it's worth, this is **not** trivial at all. You're not being stupid for asking, of course!)

Comment: Thanks -- this makes a lot more sense now. (Although, did you mean to write "$\lim A$" instead of "$\sup A$" to define the set in your comment above?)

Comment: @Will: No, I'm pretty sure that I meant to write $\sup$. Why would you think that I would mean $\lim$? (Honestly, Pierre showed me this two weeks ago, and I'm pulling this now out of memory, so I might be mistaken.)

Comment: Asaf, isn't it easier just to argue like this: let $f(A)=f_\alpha(A\cap\alpha)$ where $\alpha=\sup(A)$.  Now, the point is that for any countable $A$, after removing finitely many points, the sup won't change and won't be an element, so there can be no free descending sequence, since eventually those finitely many points on top will be removed, so it will be a free descending sequence for the limsup $\alpha$, contrary to choice of $f_\alpha$.

Comment: @Joel: But then it's not necessarily isotone, since $f_\omega$ and $f_{\omega+\omega}$ can be very different. You need to somehow integrate the counterexamples, and you're using regularity to ensure that this remains well-defined for every countable set, since it's bounded. My initial thought when I saw this was Magidor filters and Magidor cardinals, since there you're interested in bounded-countable-sets, which in this case you can also integrate over to ensure counterexamples don't appear.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. You've got to add in all the smaller guys.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Writing "lim" instead of "sup" will result in exactly the same function, so it doesn't matter which one you pick.

Comment: But then why don't you just use $f(A)=\bigcup f_\alpha(A\cap \alpha)$ for all $\alpha$ in the closure of $A$. This is now isotone, and there is no free descending sequence, since eventually after removing the finitely many points on top, the sup $\alpha$ won't change, and it would have been free descending for $f_\alpha$. No need for refining.

Comment: @Joel: Yeah, that might also work. I guess that there are many different ways to integrate these counterexamples (and in the case the sequence is of order type $\omega$, these would usually turn up equivalent).

Comment: Indeed, your function doesn't seem to be isotone, since you didn't use the closure of $A$ as in my definition, since you added $\sup(A)$, but not the other limit points of $A$, which might be $\sup(B)$ for some $B\subset A$. (But in my definition, I should have added $A\cap\alpha$ infinite, as you did.)

Comment: @Joel: Yes. I think that we converged on a fairly correct integration. :-)

Comment: I think it is simplest to use $f(A)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A'}f_\alpha(A\cap\alpha)$, that is, use only $\alpha$ that are limit points of $A$. This is isotone, and there is no free descending sequence, since after finitely many steps the sup $\alpha$ will stop changing and it would contradict the choice of $f_\alpha$. This also shows that for $\kappa$ of cofinality $\omega$, there is a function all of whose free descending sequences, if any, have order type exactly $\omega$.

Comment: @Joel: Ah, so you remove some finitely many points, perhaps, to get to a tighter definition. But in any case, if there is a free desc. seq., you can always refine it to have order type $\omega$ anyway. So I'm not sure what the extra assumption that *all* such sequences have order type $\omega$ gives you. (Not to mention that this is only for *one* function anyway...)

Comment: I had meant that the finitely many points are removed during the free descent, since you remove them all one at a time. But I agree, it might not be useful.

Comment: The conditions are set up with devilish cunning: remove the "isotone" condition or just relax it a tiny bit allowing a finite number of elements to stick out, and the answer is trivially "No". Allow outputs of cardinality $c$ (keeping countable inputs) and you get a trivial "No" again. So everything is just right on the edge,,, Still thinking (though falling asleep slowly...)

Comment: This is all I know so far. Call two countable sets equivalent if the symmetric difference is finite. The question is equivalent to asking whether for every $X$, there is a mapping $F$ of equivalence classes $q$ to actual countable sets $F(q)\subset X$ such that $q<F(q)$ and $q<r\Longrightarrow F(q)\subset F(r)$ where $q<s$ means that the representatives of $q$ are contained in (the representatives of) $s$ up to finitely many elements.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a long, possibly unhelpful comment making use of a presumably excessive large cardinal assumption.

Suppose that $\lambda$ is an uncountable cardinal and that there is a nontrivial elementary embedding
$j \colon L(V_{\lambda + 1}) \to L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ with critical point less than $\lambda$. So we are assuming that the large cardinal axiom I0 holds (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-into-rank), with $\lambda$ here as the $\lambda$ there.

Note that  (1) $j(\lambda) = \lambda$, (2), $j[\lambda]$ is in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ and (3) $[\lambda]^{\omega} \subseteq L(V_{\lambda + 1})$.

It seems that $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ thinks that $\lambda$ is an $X$ as desired.

Claim : In $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$, for any $f : [\lambda]^{\omega} \to [\lambda]^{\omega}$ (not necessarily isotone)  there exist an $\alpha < \lambda$ and an $X \subseteq \lambda$ of cardinality $\lambda$ such that $\alpha$ is not in $\bigcup f[[X]^{\omega}]$.

Applying the claim iteratively ought to let us build an independent family for any given $f$ in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$.
The output of our iterative construction is then in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$, showing that $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ thinks that $\lambda$ is as desired. Note that $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ is not a model of Choice, so maybe this doesn't address the question.

Proof of claim. Let $f : [\lambda]^{\omega} \to [\lambda]^{\omega}$ in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ be given. Let $Z$ denote $j[\lambda]$. Let $\alpha$ be an element of $\lambda \setminus Z$ (for instance, the critical point of $j$). If $x$ is a countable subset of $Z$, then $x = j(y)$ for some $y \in [\lambda]^{\omega}$ (the pointwise $j$-preimage of $x$), so $j(f)(x) = j(f(y))$, which is contained in $Z$, so $j(f)(x)$ does not have $\alpha$ as a member. Then, in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$, $Z$ is a subset of $\lambda$ of cardinality $\lambda$, and $\alpha$ is not in  $\bigcup j(f)[[Z]^{\omega}]$. By the elementarity of $j$, then, we have the conclusion of the claim : there exist an $\alpha < \lambda$ and an $X \subseteq \lambda$ of cardinality $\lambda$ such that $\alpha$ is not in $\bigcup f[[X]^{\omega}]$.

Since I'm not using the isotone condition, then at least one of the following should hold : (1) I'm making a mistake (very likely), (2) the first sentence of the December 7 comment above uses more Choice than holds in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ or (3) I0 is inconsistent.

Comment: Which December 7th comment? Can you provide a link to it? (the timestamp functions as a direct link.)

Comment: Also, Pierre was interested in models of ZFC. But I will talk to him today and see what he has to say on your answer.

Comment: When you "build the function iteratively", how do you choose $X$ at each step? In fact, how do you actually construct the family?

Comment: The iterative construction I had in mind was : pick $\alpha_{0}$ and $X_{0}$ by the claim such that $\alpha_{0}$ is not in the image of $[X_{0}]^{\omega}$; since $X_{0}$ has cardinality $\lambda$, we can apply the claim to the restriction of $f$ to $X_{0}$ to find $\alpha_{1}$ in $X_{0}$ and $X_{1} \subseteq X_{0}$ witnessing the claim for this restriction. Continuing in this way, the resulting set of $\alpha_{i}$'s should be as desired.

Comment: This comment (from fedja on Dec 7 at 4:45) : 'remove the "isotone" condition or just relax it a tiny bit allowing a finite number of elements to stick out, and the answer is trivially "No".' [None of my attempts to make tags seem to work.]

Comment: Uh, but why is the choice of $X_n$ canonical in any sort of way? I mean, countable choice fails in $L(V_{\lambda+1})$, if I recall correctly. No? As for the comment by fedja, Pierre commented on this today that probably the idea is to start with any $f$, then for every equivalence class (mod finite) choose a representative $A$ and declare $g(B)=f(A)$ whenever $B$ is equivalent to the representative $A$. Now this property has to fail, since a free dec. seq. gives a constant answer, and we can assume that $f$ satisfied $x\subseteq f(x)$ meaning most of the $x_n$'s are in the corresponding $f$.

Comment: But choosing representatives for mod finite from $[\lambda]^\omega$ requires a lot more choice than you'd have in $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ anyway.

Comment: You can run the construction in $V$, with each step carried out in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$. All you need is the output, which is a countable subset of $\lambda$. The whole output is codable by a subset of $\lambda$ anyway.

Comment: It sounds like this should be doable from ZF+Reinhardt, if it is doable from ZFC+I0. But you argue "outside the universe", which I find a bit odd.

Comment: This seems to give that the existence of a Reinhardt cardinal is inconsistent with ZF + DC plus a selector for the mod-finite equivalence classes of the countable subsets of the first fixed point (above the critical point). I don't know if this was previously known.

Comment: Arguing outside the universe is what absoluteness is for.

Comment: Isn't there a proof that a Reinhardt cardinal implies the consistency of ZFC+I0 that sort of goes through adding bits and odds of choice that should allow this proof to go through?

Comment: Okay, so $L(V_{\lambda+1})\models\sf DC_\lambda$, which would indeed give us a sequence. But in any case, I don't think that this necessarily contradicts a Reinhardt cardinal. And won't a selector function on $[\lambda]^\omega$ mod. finite with combination of $\sf DC$ give you some semblance of one of the usual inconsistency proofs in $\sf ZFC$ anyway?

Comment: Having looked at it a little more, I think that this is close to Kunen's original proof, including a proof of the Erdos-Hajnal theorem.

Comment: Okay... I'm confused now...